# SCAN command performance with phpredis

Tags: redis, phpredis

I'm replacing KEYS with SCAN using phpredis.

```
$redis = new Redis();
$redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);
$redis->setOption(Redis::OPT_SCAN, Redis::SCAN_RETRY);
$it = NULL;
while($arr_keys = $redis->scan($it, "mykey:*", 10000)) {
    foreach($arr_keys as $str_key) {
        echo "Here is a key: $str_key\n";
    }
}
```

According to [redis documentation](http://redis.io/commands/keys), I use SCAN to paginate searches to avoid disadvantage of using KEYS. 
But in practice, using above code costs me 3 times lower than using just a single `$redis->keys()` 
So I'm wondering if I've done something wrong, or I have to pay speed to avoid KEYS's threat?

Note that I totally have 400K+ keys in my db, and 4 `mykey:*` keys

Answer (score 6):

A word of caution of using the example:

```
$it = NULL;
while($arr_keys = $redis->scan($it, "mykey:*", 10000)) {
    foreach($arr_keys as $str_key) {
        echo "Here is a key: $str_key\n";
    }
}
```

That can return empty array's if none of the 10000 keys scanned matches and then it will give up, and you didn't get all the keys you wanted! I would recommend doing more like this:

```
$it = null;
do
{
    $arr_keys = $redis->scan($it, $key, 10000);
    if (is_array($arr_keys) && !empty($arr_keys))
    {
        foreach ($arr_keys as $str_key)
        {
            echo "Here is a key: $str_key\n";
        }
    }
} while ($arr_keys !== false);
```

And why it takes so long, 400k+ keys, 10000, that's 40 scan requests to redis, if it's not on the local machine, add latency for every 40 redis query to your speed.

Answer (score 5):

Since using `keys` in production environments is just forbidden because it blocks the entire server while iterating global space keys, then, there's no discussion here about use or not to use `keys`.

In the other hand, if you want to speed up things, you should go further with Redis: you should index your data.

I doubt that these 400K keys couldn't be categorized in sets or sorted sets, or even hashes, so when you need a particular subset of your 400K-keys-database you could run any `scan`-equivalent command against a set of 1K items, instead of 400K.

Redis is about indexing data. If not, you're using it like just a simple key-value store.

Comment: Indeed, the database is not mine and I'm also new to Redis, and your answer give me a hint, I'll need to dive deeper into it to achieve my goal.
Many thanks

Comment: @LoiDang Yeah, it's not that easy. BTW, mistakes in Redis can be paid hard. You really need a well-tailored database to being able to work with Redis efficiently